# Building Qt cross compile from windows

Tags: c++, qt, cross-compiling

**[edit] Sorry, I out thought myself.  I was using a .bat file to set environment variables that wasn't set up properly.  When I went to a straight VS2005 command prompt, the configure ran fine.  Sorry for the noise.[/edit]**

I'm trying to compile qt-everywhere-opensource for embedded.  I'm using MSVC2005.  However, I guess I am confused on the process.  I am getting compiler errors during the configure step.  I thought the configure step was just trying to generate the needed makefiles, so I'm not sure what it is trying to compile.

I expected to modify the mkspec, but I'm not sure if during configure I should point to windows headers or sdk headers.  I know during the build phase I should point to sdk headers, but I'm not getting that far.

I can change the errors by modifying INCPATH, there's also a QMAKE_INCDIR that seems to have an effect.  It occurred to me that since I pulled the source, maybe configure needs to build the compiler tools, in which case I should point to MSVC headers.  I also tried downloading the SDK and adding the path to it's bin folder to my path ahead of the -everywhere- source, but that didn't fix the problem and I don't want to jack up my system too much testing things.

Hope someone out there can help!

Comment: What errors are you getting? Post them here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install Qt from source under Win32, you must:

1. Extend the `PATH` variable to include `$(QTDIR)\bin`, where `$(QTDIR)` is the directory where you installed Qt.
2. Open a **Visual Studio command prompt** in `$(QTDIR)`; a plain old Windows command prompt won't do (unless you run `vcvars.bat` to load Visual Studio's environment variables; but opening a Visual Studio command prompt directly is better).

At this point, `configure` should run properly, after which you can run `nmake`.

I suggest that you clear your previous installation attempts from your system before you try these steps.